# Grouping on a column which has multiple Groups of Duplicate data

Tags: t-sql, date, range, grouping, gaps-and-islands

I need to group some data based on dates at locations including identifying when a range of dates has no location.  I'm some of the way there in that I have managed to produce a list of ALL the dates in the range and the location.

- date1   location1
- date2   location1
- date3   location1
- date4   Unknown
- date5   Unknown
- date6   Unknown
- date7   Location2
- date8   Location2
- date9   Location2
- date10  Location2
- date11  location1
- date12  location1
- date13  location1

using a normal group by (showing min(date) and max(date) I would get something like:

- Location1,date1,date13
- Location2,date7,date10
- Unknown,  date4,date6

But I want this:

- Location1,date1,date3
- Unknown,date4,date6
- Location2,date7,date9
- Location1,date11,date13

I also need to filter out short ranges of Unknown but that's secondary.

I hope this makes sense, it looks like something that should be really easy.

Comment: this is a gaps-and-islands question. I'm not sure how to add tags though...perhaps it will get auto-applied now that this comment mentions it?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into the Islands and Gaps problem and Itzik Ben-gan. There is a set based way to get the results you want.

I was looking into using ROW_NUMBER or RANK, but then I stumbled upon LAG and LEAD (introduced in SQL 2012) which are nice. I've got the solution below. It could definitely be simplified, but having it as several CTEs makes my thought process (as flawed as it may be) easier to see. I just slowly transform the data into what I want. Uncomment one select at a time if you want to see what each new CTE produces.

```
create table Junk
(aDate Datetime,
aLocation varchar(32))

insert into Junk values
('2000', 'Location1'),
('2001', 'Location1'),
('2002', 'Location1'),
('2004', 'Unknown'),
('2005', 'Unknown'),
('2006', 'Unknown'),
('2007', 'Location2'),
('2008', 'Location2'),
('2009', 'Location2'),
('2010', 'Location2'),
('2011', 'Location1'),
('2012', 'Location1'),
('2013', 'Location1'),
('2014', 'Location3')


;WITH StartsMiddlesAndEnds AS
(
    select
    aLocation, 
    aDate, 
    CASE(LAG(aLocation) OVER (ORDER BY aDate, aLocation)) WHEN aLocation THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [isStart],
    CASE(LEAD(aLocation) OVER (ORDER BY aDate, aLocation)) WHEN aLocation THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [isEnd]
    from Junk 
)
--select * from NumberedStartsMiddlesAndEnds
,NumberedStartsAndEnds AS --let's get rid of the rows that are in the middle of consecutive date groups
(
    select 
    aLocation,
    aDate,
    isStart,
    isEnd,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY aDate, aLocation) i
    FROM StartsMiddlesAndEnds 
    WHERE NOT(isStart = 0 AND isEnd = 0) --it is a middle row
)
--select * from NumberedStartsAndEnds
,CombinedStartAndEnds AS --now let's put the start and end dates in the same row
(
    select
    rangeStart.aLocation,
    rangeStart.aDate [aStart],
    rangeEnd.aDate [aEnd]
    FROM NumberedStartsAndEnds rangeStart
    join NumberedStartsAndEnds rangeEnd ON rangeStart.aLocation = rangeEnd.aLocation
    WHERE rangeStart.i = rangeEnd.i - 1 --consecutive rows
    and rangeStart.isStart = 1
    and rangeEnd.isEnd = 1
)
--select * from CombinedStartAndEnds
,OneDateIntervals AS --don't forget the cases where a single row is both a start and end
(
    select
    aLocation,
    aDate [aStart],
    aDate [aEnd]
    FROM NumberedStartsAndEnds
    WHERE isStart = 1 and isEnd = 1
)
--select * from OneDateIntervals
select aLocation, DATEPART(YEAR, aStart) [start], DATEPART(YEAR, aEnd) [end] from OneDateIntervals
UNION
select aLocation, DATEPART(YEAR, aStart) [start], DATEPART(YEAR, aEnd) [end] from CombinedStartAndEnds
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR, aStart)
```

and it produces

```
aLocation   start   end
Location1   2000    2002
Unknown 2004    2006
Location2   2007    2010
Location1   2011    2013
Location3   2014    2014
```

Don't have 2012? Then you can still get the same StartsMiddlesAndEnds CTE using ROW_NUMBER:

```
;WITH NumberedRows AS
(
    SELECT aLocation, aDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY aDate, aLocation) [i] FROM Junk
)
,StartsMiddlesAndEnds AS
(
    select
    currentRow.aLocation, 
    currentRow.aDate, 
    CASE upperRow.aLocation WHEN currentRow.aLocation THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [isStart],
    CASE lowerRow.aLocation WHEN currentRow.aLocation THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [isEnd]
    from
    NumberedRows currentRow
    left outer join NumberedRows upperRow on upperRow.i = currentRow.i-1
    left outer join NumberedRows lowerRow on lowerRow.i = currentRow.i+1
)
--select * from StartsMiddlesAndEnds
```

Comment: It looks great but we're still on 2008 and I get a Parallel Data Warehouse error (that's a new one on me).  Unfortunately I've also missed out something else that is important which I will outline separately.

Comment: I added a way to do it with 2008 (i.e. not using LAG and LEAD).